# Server settings for Ubuntu, ZF2 with AssetManager

Tags: apache, zend-framework2, ubuntu-14.04

Up until now I have been using ZF2 on a CENTOS environment with cpanel. I recently decided to move to Ubuntu and so far it has been really simple to setup a server.

I am however having a small permission problem which I am struggling to resolve.

I am using AssetManage which needs to be able to write images and files to the public folder.

Unfortunately, I cant seem to get the correct permissions to get this to work.

I have gone as far as setting 777 permissions to the public folder which makes no difference.

I have also changed the owner of public to: www-data which is the user that apache is using, and this does not help either.

What is likely the problem is the user/group I am using to load files to the server conflicting with the www-data user needing to perform various tasks on the server.

Is there a standard setup I should be looking at in terms of this?

SETUP:

Ubuntu: 14.4
ZF2

Comment: Which AssetManager? Do you have some Code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found some great tutorials to setup an Ubuntu environment. Here they are:

1. [Basic installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04)
2. Enhanced installation
3. LAMP stack

All working perfectly now!